# Withdrawing Ether to another Wallet Problem

Tags: solidity, ico

I'm trying to write something like ICO projects do and I got this problem when it comes to withdraw the ether in the contract's balance to my wallet.

```
function withdrawal () public payable 
{                       
    address bank = 0x...... ;
    address myAddress = this;
    require(myAddress.balance >= 1000000000000000);
    bank.transfer(address(this).balance);

   }
```

When the contract has ether in it, nothing happens. It doesn't even try to send it. So I'm wondering what I am doing wrong, or if there is a better way to do it. Thanks in advance guys, appreciate every answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suspec that your contract doesn't actually have a valid balance and/or `require(myAddress.balance >= 1000000000000000);` is your problem. You should change this to `require(address(this).balance >= 1000000000000000)` 
That being said this is incredibly inefficient code and can be better written as

```
contract ICO {
    address public bank = ......;

    function withdrawal() public {
        require(address(this).balance >= 1000000000000000);
        bank.transfer(address(this).balance);
    }

}
```

Also make sure the address declare as `bank` isn't a contract, and if it is, that it has a payable fallback function, otherwise this will also fail

edit:

Due to the way your code written I suspect you are quite new to solidity, and don't yet understand all the gotchas, intricacies, and tricks that come to writting solidity smart contracts. I would recommend trying simpler contracts first, and become better affiliated with the language before attempting to write ICO contracts.

https://github.com/ConsenSys/smart-contract-best-practices

https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/ERC20_Token_Standard

http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/introduction-to-smart-contracts.html